# Check Caret Browsing On\Off

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I know it isn't possible to disable\enable IE Caret Browsing from javascript,
But is it possible to identify whether or not it is enabled or disabled currently?

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Go to

```
about:config
```

in address bar, search for **caret**. 
Check status of **accessibility.browsewithcaret**

Comment: that isn't "from javascript"